# ActionMailer Not Sending Emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I set up ActionMailer on an example rails app and action-mailer seems to not be delivering emails.

It's a fairly simple setup, when a user creates an account, they automatically receive a welcome email from the site!

production.rb

```
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  # SMTP settings for gmail
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
   :port                 => 587,
   :user_name            => ENV['gmail_username'],
   :password             => ENV['gmail_password'],
   :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

user_controller.rb

```
    def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save

        # Sends email to user when user is created.
        ExampleMailer.sample_email(@user).deliver

        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
  end
```

My gmail username and password are successfully set using Figaro.
Also, my Gmail settings are set to allow less secure apps.

What's going on here?

Comment: Do you have an error message? If you run `ExampleMailer.sample_email(User.first).deliver` in your IRB on production mode, what is the output?

Comment: I ran the above command in my production console I I received the following error:

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC

Comment: Also note that when I ran `ExampleMailer.sample_email(User.first).deliver` in my development console, I received no error.

Comment: After reading the error, it seems that you didn't run the migrations in production or there is something wrong in your database.

Comment: I actually didn't run the migrations. I have now, but I get the follow new error:

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass

Comment: It seems to be tripping up on the following code: `mail(to: user.email, subject: 'Sample Email!')` in my `example_mailer.rb`